# Merge rows by ID and date - Pandas

Tags: pandas

I've got data frame with IDs, dates per ID and times per date.
Also, a binary variable that gets 1 when weekend, 0 otherwise, and another binary variable - Y (no matter what it indicates).
I want to merge rows by ID and date, and keep on weekend value per (ID, date),
and get 1 on Y variable if Y got 1 in any row at (ID, date) level, 0 otherwise.

- Note: ID, Date and Time are indices, and they are sorted.

Data illustration:

```
ID  Date        Time    Weekend Y
1   08/27/2019  18:00   0       1
                19:00   0       0
    08/28/2019  08:00   1       1
                09:00   1       1
2   07/07/2019  18:00   0       0
                19:00   0       0
    07/08/2019  08:00   0       1
                09:00   0       0
                10:00   0       0
```

Expected result:

```
ID  Date        Weekend Y
1   08/27/2019  0       1
    08/28/2019  1       1
2   07/07/2019  0       0
    07/08/2019  0       1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with `max`

```
df.max(level=[0,1])
```